# Order data coming to my Python console from another computer using sockets

Tags: python, python-2.7

I took some data from another computer connected to mine. It sends data continuously and I want to order it. In the first line I have 9 unwanted white spaces but the other lines are ok.

First, I want to ignore the spaces on the first line, and then I want to order the lines under each other, or just order them in any way.

Here's what the data I'm getting from the socket looks like:

```
4133193  -1.45000000000e-07  -5.40000000000e-08
-3.70000000000e-08                   0  -3.78920000000e-04
-6.79840000000e-04  -4.95466000000e-02                   0
4.74765625000e+01   4.99850000000e-03   5.04500000000e-03

4133194  -3.11000000000e-07   3.40000000000e-08
-8.11000000000e-07                   0  -3.83260000000e-04
-6.84720000000e-04  -4.89480000000e-02                   0
4.74765625000e+01   5.00100000000e-03   4.98350000000e-03

4133195  -3.10000000000e-07   2.17000000000e-07
-1.70000000000e-07                   0  -3.86180000000e-04
-8.05420000000e-04  -4.88261200000e-02                   0
4.74765625000e+01   4.99850000000e-03   4.98350000000e-03
```

Each 4 line block is one message that comes to my console, and I will have 200 messages. I want to order them and then find the mean of some columns and so on. But first I just want to show the numbers of each message under each other.

I want the second row to be something like:

```
4133194 -3.11 3.4 ... till 4.9835
```

with the numbers of each row aligned in columns.

The code I'm using to get this data is:

```
import time
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(('.........', 2015))

for i in range(0, 20):
    OU = sock.recv(2048)
    print OU

sock.close()
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. What do you want the output to look like? For example, do you want one number printed on each line?

Comment: let me make more clear: each 4 line (as you see above) is one message that come to my console. and i will have 200 messages. i want to order them and then find mean of some columns and so on. but i want toshow first numbers of each message under each other. regarding photo above i want to have somthing like:   4133194      -3.11     3.4    ..............................till 4.9835 and then as second row 4133195 (want to be under 4133194)      -3.1(want to put under-3.11) and so on.

Comment: How is this data stored in your computer?...is it stored in a file?..or you receive it and print it directly to your screen?

Comment: Can you show us some code you've written to attack this problem? You'll get _much_ better responses to questions on Stack Overflow if we can see what you've already tried.

Comment: @Khalil Ammour   it came with socket that connected to my laptop and i just wrote a socket code and print with   `print  recv (1024)` then it automatically printed 1024 KB data comes from socket to my computer.

Comment: @PM2Ring                                                                                               `import time`
`import socket`


`sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)`
`sock.bind(('.........', 2015))`



    
`for i in range(0, 20):`
        `OU = sock.recv(2048)`
        `print OU`

`sock.close()`

Comment: Now show us your attempt at some Python code that prints the data in the way that you want, even if it doesn't work properly.

Comment: @PM2Ring  first thanks for your help. i try all codes about alignment, removing spaces and so on but none of them do the things that i want. as you see from output numbers, each 4 line is one message (all are 3 message). first number of first line is message id that we have it in line 5 and 9 (first numbers), i want to put this 3 numbers under eachother in 1 column. then continue with second number of first message and put it with second number of decond message and second number of third message in one column and continue for all numbers. i stuck in this part and could not find any other way.

Comment: So each message that is received and printed by your code is composed of four lines of data plus an extra blank line at the end?

Comment: @martineau Exactly it is

Comment: @martineau: Bear in mind that these lines _may_ be terminated with CRLF, i.e., `'\r\n'`, but that shouldn't matter if you use `.strip()` or `.rstrip()` to clean them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this is all you need:

```
data_stream = ['''\
         4133193  -1.45000000000e-07  -5.40000000000e-08
-3.70000000000e-08                   0  -3.78920000000e-04
-6.79840000000e-04  -4.95466000000e-02                   0
4.74765625000e+01   4.99850000000e-03   5.04500000000e-03

''',
'''         4133194  -3.11000000000e-07   3.40000000000e-08
-8.11000000000e-07                   0  -3.83260000000e-04
-6.84720000000e-04  -4.89480000000e-02                   0
4.74765625000e+01   5.00100000000e-03   4.98350000000e-03

''',
'''         4133195  -3.10000000000e-07   2.17000000000e-07
-1.70000000000e-07                   0  -3.86180000000e-04
-8.05420000000e-04  -4.88261200000e-02                   0
4.74765625000e+01   4.99850000000e-03   4.98350000000e-03

''']

for message in data_stream:
    print ' '.join(message.split())
```

Output:

```
4133193 -1.45000000000e-07 -5.40000000000e-08 -3.70000000000e-08 0 -3.78920000000e-04 -6.79840000000e-04 -4.95466000000e-02 0 4.74765625000e+01 4.99850000000e-03 5.04500000000e-03
4133194 -3.11000000000e-07 3.40000000000e-08 -8.11000000000e-07 0 -3.83260000000e-04 -6.84720000000e-04 -4.89480000000e-02 0 4.74765625000e+01 5.00100000000e-03 4.98350000000e-03
4133195 -3.10000000000e-07 2.17000000000e-07 -1.70000000000e-07 0 -3.86180000000e-04 -8.05420000000e-04 -4.88261200000e-02 0 4.74765625000e+01 4.99850000000e-03 4.98350000000e-03
```

Comment: and as my last question, after make them in columns , is it possible to give a little space between columns too?

Comment: Sure, just add more whitespace in the `'  '` part of the `join()` call.